# $localStorage is not adding new items with the old items

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage

I want to add new items into $localStorage plus old items. But, here in my code $localStorage loosing all previous items. My code is as follows,

```js
        $scope.cart = [];   

        $scope.cart = productService.getSharedProduct();        

       if ($scope.cart != 0) {
           
           $localStorage.items = $scope.cart;
       }

       else {
           $scope.cart = $localStorage.items;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because you are not adding items to your `$localStorage.items` but you are assigning new values to it every time and so it lost the last added values.
You are re-initializing them every time and so they loose last added values.

You should do something like this

```
if ($scope.cart != 0) {

    // instead of this            
    //$localStorage.items = $scope.cart; 

    // you should do this
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.cart.length; i++)
    {
        $localStorage.items.push($scope.cart[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please mark the answer correct if it works for you (by clicking on the check mark on my answer)